# Get only blog posts where I'm not the last commenter

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a list of blog posts, people can leave comments and I reply to them

This is how the structure looks like

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9BQX.png)

Is there a way, with a single query, to get all posts where I'm not the last person to leave a comment?

Ideally I would want something like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM posts
INNER JOIN comments
WHERE # I'm not the last person to leave a comment
```

Here is an online example : https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3zsb5urne
I'm using MySQL 8 but I don't know if it matters.

These are some of the things I tried (among many, many others...)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM comments
ORDER BY created_at desc
WHERE post_id = 1
LIMIT 1
```

I also tried this

```sql
SELECT user_id, max(created_at)
FROM comments
GROUP BY post_id
```

but it doesn't work because `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

(not sure if this is a valid query in the 1st place)

However I'm not sure how to combine/join this to with the `posts` table so that it limits the results for each post.

Comment: @user1191247 Ah, you are correct. Should be the other way around. I believe it's fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) window function like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, user_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM comments
) c ON p.id = c.post_id AND c.rn = 1 AND c.user_id <> 1;
```

Or you could use some subqueries like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT post_id
    FROM comments
    WHERE (post_id, created_at) IN (
        SELECT post_id, MAX(created_at)
        FROM comments
        GROUP BY post_id
    )
    AND user_id <> 1
);
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pGnlExFW).

**Note**: neither of these show posts that do not have any comments.

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I needed! Would it be a major change to also show posts that do not have comments?

Comment: I have updated the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pGnlExFW) with a couple of examples.

Comment: Truly an unsung hero... I can't even upvote your answer...